# Ubuntu Server 18.10 LTE: after reboot can't connect to network

Tags: networking, server, 18.10, static-ip

I just installed Ubuntu server, and I assigned it the IPv4 as static (no collisions). I rebooted my server after installation, and it was trying to connect to network for a while (2-3 minutes) and then it started the terminal and couldn't connect to network (can't ping google or DG). 
I've ran ifconfig command and the results were that the connection isn't active and send/receive 0 bytes. What can I do? in other installation it happend too (on the same server, of course)

pc from 2009, 4gb ram, intel pentium, and adapter is fine.

Comment: Where did you set the static IP address? In netplan? May we troubleshoot your file? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the output from `ip a`? What kind of network card? What was *stuck* trying to connect? [Edit] your post and include as much information as possible.